# Access image folder outside of WordPress folder

Tags: php, wordpress

Can a folder outside of the WordPress directory but still on the server be accessed through WordPress?

I can successfully access files inside my theme folder but I am trying to access a folder full of images outside of the WordPress folder.

What changes need to be made?

```
$home_directory = site_url();
$home_uri       = home_url();

$vendorLogo = $home_uri. '/clientimages/directory/logo' . $vendor->acctno . '.png';

if ( file_exists( $home_directory . $vendorLogo ) ) {
  echo '<br>';
  printf( '<img class="vendorImage" src="%s"/>', esc_url( $home_uri . $vendorLogo ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a multisite? If not then you should be able to access it with a complete URL  like http://www.example.com which would be the root of your domain and you probably can't get past that unless it's your own server.  You can also try relative URL's like ../ which will get you one directory higher than where your at. Most Wordpress sites get installed in a subdirectory one level below the root and the path to the themes directory is something like this:
**/installation subdirectory/wp-content/themes/theme directory**.  If you use a path that starts with a forward slash the Wordpress will add the home_url for you.

So if your trying to get another logo image then you can try http://yourdomain.com/ then add the path to when your image resides.

You can also load images with your media library and in that case you can upload them from your computer thus giving you access to the rest of the world.  You can get the url to those images from the media library.

Comment: Not on multisite. I used complete url: 'htttp://mydomain.com/thepath' and still not able to access files outside of Wordpress folder.

Comment: Can you access that image via ftp?  Or can you access it with your browser?  If so, either of those will allow you to get the file on your computer and then upload it to your media center which will save it to an accessible location.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to FTP into the web-root, where you can see both the wordpress installation and the clientimages directory, then you should use the following in the .htaccess file in the web-root.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Do nothing if the request is for a valid directory, file or link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Make sure you change the word `wordpress` to whatever the wordpress installation directory is and backup whatever you currently have in .htaccess that redirects to the wordpress folder.

Now when you request access to something that exists in the web-root, it will be available.